# Windows 10 domU broken after upgrade xen 4.1 --> 4.8

Tags: windows, windows-10, 32bit-64bit, xen

I used to have a xen 4.1 Server happily running a Windows guest (Server 2k3, then 10) domain for several years. After upgrade to Debian 9 – and xen 4.8 – this guest won't start any longer. Or rather, it starts but during boot drops into a recovery screen saying »This 64-bit application couldn't load because your PC doesn't have a 64-bit processor«.

This is the configuration file that used to work:

```
    #  -*- mode: python; -*-
import os, re
arch = os.uname()[4]
arch_libdir='lib'

kernel = "/usr/lib/xen-4.1/boot/hvmloader"
builder='hvm'
memory = 10240
shadow_memory = 64 
name = "xmW10"
vcpus=4
pae=0
acpi=1
apic=1
vif = [ 'mac=00:16:3e:00:00:11, bridge=dmz, ip=213.47.212.61' ]
disk = [ 'phy:/dev/vgmirr2/lvW10,hda,w' ] 
xen_platform_pci=1
device_model='/usr/lib/xen/bin/qemu-dm'

boot="c"
sdl=0

vnc=1
vncviewer=1
vnclisten="0.0.0.0"
vncdisplay=0
vncconsole=1
vncpasswd=''

stdvga=0
serial='pty'
localtime=0
keymap='de'
```

As variuos options are not supported any longer, it became like so:

```
builder='hvm'
memory = 10240
shadow_memory = 64 
name = "xmW10"
vcpus=4
pae=0
acpi=1
apic=1
vif = [ 'mac=00:16:3e:00:00:11, bridge=dmz, ip=213.47.212.61' ]
disk = [ 'phy:/dev/vgmirr2/lvw10,ioemu:hda,w' ,
        'file:/nodump/downloads/Win10_1703_English_x64.iso,ioemu:hdc:cdrom,r' ]
xen_platform_pci=1
device_model_version="qemu-xen"

boot="dc"
sdl=0
stdvga=0
serial='pty'
localtime=0
keymap='de'
```

I had some tries involving options ›device_model_override‹ and the like, but the result – if the domU starts at all – is invariably the recovery screen.

What am I missing?

Comment: To the downvoter: please explain what's wrong with the question, so I can amend it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed, respectively added the following parameters in the configuration file:

```
pae=1
hap=1
hpet=1
```

Now the guest comes up as usual.